# How do I suggest that the user wrap this parameter in a method call?

Tags: java, errorprone

A common problem we find in code review is people writing this:

```java
    assertThat(thing, nullValue());
```

instead of this:

```java
    assertThat(thing, is(nullValue()));
```

In order to catch it sooner, I thought I'd try writing a custom error-prone check. This is a poorly documented area though so I've been doing so by digging inside GitHub for working examples.

I have so far:

```java
@AutoService(BugChecker.class)
@BugPattern(
    name = "AssertThatThingNullValue",
    summary = "`assertThat(thing, nullValue())` doesn't sound like English, wrap `nullValue` in `is`"
    severity = WARNING)
public class AssertThatThingNullValue extends BugChecker implements MethodInvocationTreeMatcher
{
    private static final Matcher<ExpressionTree> ASSERT_THAT = staticMethod()
        .onClassAny("org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert", "org.junit.Assert")
        .named("assertThat");

    private static final Matcher<ExpressionTree> NULL_VALUE = staticMethod()
        .onClass("org.hamcrest.Matchers")
        .named("nullValue");

    private static final Matcher<ExpressionTree> NULL_VALUE_INVOCATION =
        methodInvocation(NULL_VALUE);

    private static final Matcher<ExpressionTree> ASSSERT_THAT_THING_NULL_VALUE =
        methodInvocation(ASSERT_THAT, MatchType.LAST, NULL_VALUE_INVOCATION);

    @Override
    public Description matchMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree tree, VisitorState state)
    {
        if (ASSSERT_THAT_THING_NULL_VALUE.matches(tree))
        {
            buildDescription(tree)
                .addFix(SuggestedFixes.somethingGoesHere(...))
                .build();
        }

        return Description.NO_MATCH;
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to build the suggested fix from the available methods in `SuggestedFixes`. I'm wondering whether this API just isn't fleshed out well or whether I'm just going down the wrong track entirely and should be writing the check in a better way?